# Unable to run CasperJS script file in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, casperjs

I'm very new to CasperJS & PhantomJS and after following the quickstart part of the documentation of CasperJS, everytime I open up a terminal to  write something like

```
casperjs sample.js
```

It gives me the "Unable to open file: sample.js" error. It **does** work however, if I include the whole path as such

```
casperjs C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\sample.js`
```

**Installed Software:**

Python v2.7

PhatomJS v1.9.7

CasperJS v1.1-beta3

Comment: So, you're using cmd.exe, right? Are you sure you're in the correct directory (`C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\ `)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using cmd.exe, but what do you mean by if I'm sure? The sample.js is in that directory, yes. Sorry if this is a weird question, as I said I'm very new to this.

Comment: Before calling casperjs, have you done `cd C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop`? How did you open cmd?

Comment: I opened it through start menu (windows 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic commandline usage. You first have to change into the folder where the file you want to use is. Since you "installed" CasperJS, its executable is in the PATH and is found automatically, but sample.js is a regular file which is not in PATH. So you have to either change into the directory that contains the file or use a relative path to the file.

Since you open cmd.exe from start, it will open in the directory `C:\Users\[Username]`. You have to do:

```
cd Desktop
casperjs sample.js
```

or

```
casperjs Desktop/sample.js
```

Comment: ah thank you, it just felt weird to me because you can still write things like casperjs selftest.js (selftest.js is in the \tests\ folder) and it works, but even if you put the file "sample.js" there it doesn't work

Comment: selftest.js is special because it is explicitly callable from bootstrap.js, but it should be `casperjs selftest` and not `casperjs selftest.js` judging from the code.